# Extract multiple parts of text from .txt

Tags: php

I have previosly saved a string to a .txt like this:

```
$text = "<div class='highlight'><div><p>".$date.".</p> <h1> ".$heading."</h1>".$textbox."</div></div>";
```

I now want to extract `$date`, `$heading` and `$textbox` from the txtfile back to variables, for the purpose of editing and I have no clue how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can't you make your html syntax somewhat more simple so you can use explode() otherwise you will need regex

Comment: Looks like you need to separate your template and variables. Store a template with pre-defined placeholders for variables. And store your data in a separate store. Some key-val store.

Comment: Use the below solution (posted by me) if you need to continue saving your variables in the same format as you are doing now.. But I think you need to consider above suggestions by Vikar and Webtecher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a DOM parser to parse the HTML.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Code posted from the above site.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '
';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '
';
```

OR PHP's DOM

```
$str = file_get_contents("a.txt");
   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($str);
```

//get all H1
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1');

//display all H1 text
   for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "
";

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php. You'll find a saga of information here.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit - after reading the comments it seems regex is not the way to go. Please try using SimpleHtmlDom parser]

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($yourstring);
$date = $html->find('p')->innertext;
$heading = $html->find('h1')->innertext;
$textbox = $html->find('div div')->innertext;
```

you can find the documentation for Simple Html Dom here - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

A less efficient way - 
    preg_match('#

(.*).*(.*).*(.*)#', $text, $matches);
    $date = $matches[0];
    $heading = $matches[1];
    $textBox = $matches[2];